# Magento 2 Grid System

Tags: magento2, grid, css, magento2.2, styles

I am trying to work out what grid system comes with Magento 2.2 for the frontend

I can see there are docs for the admin [Page Grid](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/design-styleguide/pagegrid/pagegrid.html) however none of the frontend. Could someone point me in the right direction or is it the case that I should include my own system like Bootstrap or UI Kit

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 does not ship with a grid system, the closest you get is some classes added to the body which you can use. For example:

```
.page-layout-1column {
    .product-info-main {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .product.media {
        width: 57%;
    }
}
```

If you want to use your own then I advise it, but allow time to fix conflicts with the UI library as I have ran into some in the past when using Bootstrap.